# Webpack / React : Inline loader Executing Without Being Called (unexpected behaviour from inline loaders with dynamic imports)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I am attempting to load an SVG, as a component, using the inline loader syntax. `require(!!svg-react-loader!./path/asset.svg)` and also load `png, jpg` images

I realise the SVG loading is easy enough with `import {Component as Asset} from "./path/to/asset.svg"`
however my import has a dynamic value in the path.

**My Code:**

```
const ThemedSVGWrapper = (props) => {
    const { svgName, svgProps } = props;
    const { theme } = useConfig(["theme"]);

    const SVGComponent = require(`!!svg-react-loader!./path/to/${theme}/assets/${svgName}`);

    return <SVGComponent {...svgProps}/>
}

const themedImageGetter = (theme, fileName) => {
    return require(`./themes/${theme}/assets/${fileName}`)
}
// SVGs
export const Logo = (props) => <ThemedSVGWrapper svgProps={props} svgName="logo.svg"></ThemedSVGWrapper>;
export const LoadingImage = (props) => <ThemedSVGWrapper svgProps={props} svgName="loading.svg"></ThemedSVGWrapper>;

export const getLoadingImageRef = (themeName) => themedImageRefWrap(themeName, "loading.svg");

// PNGs and JPGs
export const getLoginBackgroundImage = (themeName) => themedImageRefWrap(themeName, "Login-BG-Image.jpg");
export const getPageNotFoundImage = (themeName) => themedImageRefWrap(themeName, "page-not-found.png");
```

**The Problem**

When using these exports I get console errors in the browser:

```
./src/themes/default/assets/Login-BG-Image.jpg (./node_modules/svg-react-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/themes/default/assets/Login-BG-Image.jpg)
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: �
```

This to me looks like the `svg-react-loader` is being called to load the JPG and is throwing an error as it can't understand the file format.

While running a build for my production assets I get:

```
...
./node_modules/svg-react-loader/lib/loader.js ^\.\/.*$ ./default/assets/Login-BG-Image.jpg
...
```

and many other errors for all my other assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I realised the following:

Inside ThemedSVGWrapper:

```
const SVGComponent = require(`!!svg-react-loader!./path/to/${theme}/assets/${svgName}`);
```

uses a variable to determine the asset to load using the inline loader `${svgName}`.

---

Webpack when building will turn any variables in an import into regex.

Webpack then uses this regex (at build-time) to determine which files can be loaded (at run-time).

Webpack then builds a mapping to the assets it moves to the build folder

---

This means that my assets being loaded by the `require` method using the inline loader matched all assets in the assets folder.

The simple solution to this was to add `.svg` to my require function so that the regex way more choosy. 
Like so:

```
const SVGComponent = require(`!!svg-react-loader!./themes/${theme}/assets/${svgName}.svg`);
```

Hope this is helpful someone.